# Get all documents in a collection which match a set of keys - mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to find all users in my collection that match the `roleId` for multiple keys like `administrator`, `mod` and `writer`.
The `roleId` is stored as the corresponding array element.

The collection looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : "P7xfcnhvQY4mupyRs", "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-11-16T10:37:24.371Z"), "roles" : { "administrator" : [  "Y2FZnfx9Zi4NR6J6e" ] }, "services" : { "password" : { "bcrypt" : "$2a$10$rWvLQkpiQW55Cp9aF37OtOipuApzM7WKAVTLz/B3HwVypFM4uJEJy" }, "resume" : { "loginTokens" : [  {       "when" : ISODate("2014-11-16T10:37:24.376Z"),   "hashedToken" : "ER4k6eLwKHczqTUE9/7wIs/ZRGyGEPmtknEYn4MH/eM=" } ] } }, "username" : "John" }
{ "_id" : "ic6sNco6HMJJAgnuh", "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-11-16T11:06:09.697Z"), "roles" : { "writer" : [  "Y2FZnfx9Zi4NR6J6e" ] }, "services" : { "password" : { "bcrypt" : "$2a$10$BRLXmsCBD504YdZgLikgr.nNEvnRVStiQwQKaSQlZlhM138mf8cK2" }, "resume" : { "loginTokens" : [ ] } }, "username" : "Harry" }
{ "_id" : "LYAcBy58iiuZSbYhk", "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-11-16T11:06:22.854Z"), "roles" : { "mod" : [  "Y2FZnfx9Zi4NR6J6e" ] }, "services" : { "password" : { "bcrypt" : "$2a$10$Kp7.uyN0dBrl7hRBDAh/wu4niffCXpO3r6EM292xSj2useDjtx28G" }, "resume" : { "loginTokens" : [         {       "when" : ISODate("2014-11-16T11:06:22.859Z"),   "hashedToken" : "1D0uSqV3fy/LanaheiMGZPrIFzI5O3VESDrFKbrDl8g=" } ] } }, "username" : "Peter" }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your collection has 3 items with same id?

Comment: Sorry, copy-paste mistake. I corrected my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly this would be your answer

```
db.user_details.find(
{
    $or : 
    [
        {'roles.administrator' : "Y2FZnfx9Zi4NR6J6e"},
        {'roles.mod' :  "Y2FZnfx9Zi4NR6J6e"},
        {'roles.writer' : "Y2FZnfx9Zi4NR6J6e"}
    ]
})
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JohnnyHK is one of my favorite persons who answers mongo questions. How it is gonna work without $or? I tested it and got an error.

Comment: You definitely need the `$or`, I was talking about the `$in` operators.  You can just use straight matches like `'roles.administrator': 'Y2FZnfx9Zi4NR6J6e'`.